# bitshift function to shift bits in HSV image

Tags: matlab

i want to run my code below

```
img =imread(file_name);  
imgH=rgb2hsv(img);  
MSB3 = bitshift(imgH,-5);
```

but i have error

```
Error using bitshift  
Double inputs must have integer values in the range of ASSUMEDTYPE.  
Error in Encoding (line 41)  
    MSB3 = bitshift(imgH,-5);
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because when using `rgb2hsv`, it makes your image `imgH` be of type double (IEEE 754 double precision). When using `bitshift` on a double precision data type, the documentation indicates this:

```
If A is a double array, then all elements must be non-negative integers
less than or equal to intmax('uint64'), and bitshift 
drops any bits overflowing 64 bits.
```

see

```
help bitshift
```

Given this understanding of how `rgb2hsv` converts the image to a format that bitshift doesn't really play well with, I suppose you'll have to rethink your strategy of using bitshift for a HSV image, or consider potentially truncating the values in the HSV images to be integral, like how the help text indicates.